# get the value of a specific id that has a class attached to it using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the name of the div with the class of 'currentSlide attached to it.
so when i click on the nav button it looks for the div with an id of about-interior / solutions-interior / approach-interior / or contact-interior and returns the name of the div that has the class 'currentSlide' attached to it.
I hope this makes since.

so if i were to attach an alert to the click event like this ( alert(currentSlide); ) it would return for example 'about-interior'.

This is my current code, again i am wanting the name of the id that has the class currentSlide attached to it. Their will only be one div that will have an ID that ends with '-interior' and has a class of currentSlide

```
    var currentSlide = $("section[id$='-interior']").hasClass('currentSlide');
```

right now i am only able to alert that the div with the class of currentSlide exists using the .hasClass method.this is not what i want.

Sorry for making this post more difficult than it needed to be.
Here is the answer i was looking for

```
   var currentSlide = $("section[id$='-interior'].currentSlide").attr('id');
```

Comment: So...what's the question :D

Comment: trying to make a variable that contains the div that has the class of currentSlide. i used regExpression to find all tags that end with'-interior'. i want the div that contains an id that end with '-interior' and has the class of currentSlide

Comment: Like var currentSlide = $("section[id$='-interior'] .currentSlide"); ?

Comment: i tried doing what you said earlier, when i use the alert(currentSlide); it returns object object. like it is an array i guess. it should return a value like about-interior or solutions-interior. maybe i am going about this the wrong way or wording it wrong.

Comment: when i used var currentSlide = $("section[id$='-interior'].currentSlide"); and when i try using the console.log(currentSlide); this is what i get in the console when returned.        [section#about-interior.content currentSlide, prevObject: b.fn.b.init[1], context: document, selector: "section[id$='-interior'].currentSlide", jquery: "1.9.1", constructor: function…]
0: section#about-interior.content
context: document
length: 1
prevObject: b.fn.b.init[1]
selector: "section[id$='-interior'].currentSlide"
__proto__: Object[0]

Comment: @TravisMichaelHeller jQuery selectors return objects, not strings. If you want to see the ID, use `currentSlide.attr('id')`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I can't believe i didn't think of that, been staring at the comp for way too long. here is the answer i was looking for                                                                 var currentSlide = $("section[id$='-interior'].currentSlide").attr('id');

Answer (score 0):

Just add the class inside the selector:

```
var currentSlide = $("section[id$='-interior'].currentSlide");
```

Should give you an array of `section`s with ID's ending in `interior` that have the class `currentSlide`